# ESP-IDF: no module named '_curses'

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, esp32, esp-idf

I am working on a project using ESP32 DevKit board, using ESP-IDF . I cannot open *menuconfig* in ESP-IDF CMD.

I am working on a project using ESP32 DevKit board, using the ESP-IDF extension on Visual Studio Code (WINDOWS). I was able to run the examples provided by Espressif, and also open the menuconfig on Visual Studio and modify parameters.

I moved to ESP-IDF cmd and ran `idf.py menuconfig` in the project folder. I received this message:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'`

I have installed windows-curses:

`pip install windows-curses` but I still have the same issue.

I have pip-23.2, Windows 10, ESP-IDF v5.1 and ESP-IDF extension for VS Code v1.6.4

¿Could you give me a solution either in the ESP-IDF CMD or the VS Code extension?

Answer (score 0):

you must do pip install windows-curses in esp-idf terminal, not in cmd or powershell.

or you can access menuconfig with click "gear" icon in left bottom corner od vscode
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYTum.png)